# Mysql Can't start server: can't create PID file: Invalid argument

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I have some problems with EasyPhp. The Apache file is green, but MySql is red. It can not be connected. this is the log file:

> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
>   disabled
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   Windows  interlocked functions
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
>   1.2.3
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
>   instructions
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size
>   = 20.0M
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format
>   is Barracuda.
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers
>   1625977 and 1625977 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence
>   number 1626134 in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown
>   normally!
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information
>   from the .ibd files...
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible
>   half-written data pages
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are
>   active.
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:08 3676 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.15 started; log sequence
>   number 1626134
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:09 3676 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so
>   we assume that this is the first time that this server has been
>   started. Generating a new UUID: 95c8d95a-9e70-11e5-96af-9f51bab14854.
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:09 3676 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address):
>   '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:09 3676 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to
>   '127.0.0.1';
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:09 3676 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
>   '127.0.0.1'.
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:09 3676 [ERROR]
>   C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\mysql\bin\eds-mysqld.exe: Can't
>   create/write to file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\binaries\mysql\data\Daniela-??.pid'
>   (Errcode: 22 - Invalid argument)
>
> 2015-12-09 15:30:09 3676 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID
>   file: Invalid argument
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
>   disabled
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
>   1.2.3
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
>   instructions
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size
>   = 20.0M
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format
>   is Barracuda.
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the
>   checkpoint lsn 1626134
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown
>   normally!
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information
>   from the .ibd files...
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible
>   half-written data pages
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:16 1928 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
>   InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1626144
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are
>   active.
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.15 started; log sequence
>   number 1626144
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] Recovering after a crash using
>   mysql-bin
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address):
>   '127.0.0.1';  port: 3306
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to
>   '127.0.0.1';
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
>   '127.0.0.1'.
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [ERROR]
>   C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~1.1VC\binaries\mysql\bin\eds-mysqld.exe: Can't
>   create/write to file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\binaries\mysql\data\Daniela-??.pid'
>   (Errcode: 22 - Invalid argument)
>
> 2015-12-09 21:12:18 1928 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID
>   file: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into the `my.ini` file in easyPHP mysql-installed folder.
2. Below the line `innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50` add `innodb_flush_method=normal`.
3. Restart it.

Reference from [easyphp failing to load after installing windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124653/easyphp-failing-to-load-after-installing-windows-10)